# Check the type of an enumerated class

Tags: if-statement, ceylon

I have an enumerated abstract class:

```
shared abstract class Foo() of bar|baz {}
```

And a function that attempts to check if a `Foo` is not a `bar`:

```
shared void test(Foo foo) {
    if (!is bar foo) {

    }
}
```

I get the error

```
incorrect syntax: no viable alternative at token 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gdejohn's answer is correct, but I would also note that it doesn't *usually* make much sense to directly refer to the type of an enumerated instance. Usually you would write the code like this:

```
void test(Foo foo) {
    if (foo!=bar) {
        print("Not bar!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed that you usually don't care to narrow the type. The situation where it would make sense is if `bar` or `baz` declared new attributes or methods that you wanted to use.

Comment: There's another even more interesting usecase: where you want to narrow the set of options down to a subset of the instances, for example, a type like: `\Ioption1|\Ioption4|\Ioption5`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `bar` is an enumerated instance, it's just a value, not a type. But it does have a more specific type than `Foo`, which you can denote by prefixing it with `\I`.

```
void test(Foo foo) {
    if (!is \Ibar foo) {
        print("Not bar!");
    }
}
```